# Idris parser combinator GADT

Tags: parsing, types, gadt, idris

I am currently working on implementing a simple parser combinator library in Idris to learn the language and better understand type systems in general, but am having some trouble wrapping my head around how GADTs are declared and used. The parser data type that I am trying to formulate looks like (in Haskell): `type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]`, from [this](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monparsing.pdf) paper. Basically, the type is a function that takes a string and returns a list.

In Idris I have:

```
data Parser : Type -> Type where
    fail : a -> (String -> [])
    pass : a -> (String -> [(a,String)])
```

where the `fail` instance is a parser that always fails (i.e.- will be a function that always returns the empty list) and the `pass` instance is a parser that consumed some symbol. When loading the above into the interpreter, I get an error that there is a type mismatch between `List elem` and the expected type `Type`. But when I check the returned type of the parser in the repl with `:t String -> List Type` I get `Type`, which looks like it should work.

I would be very grateful if anyone could give a good explanation of why this data declaration does not work, or a better alternative to representing the parser data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell,

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]
```

doesn't create a new type, it is merely a type synonym. You can do something similar in Idris as

```
Parser : Type -> Type
Parser a = String -> List (a, String)
```

and then define your helper definitions as simple functions that return `Parser a`s:

```
fail : Parser a
fail = const []

pass : a -> Parser a
pass x = \s => [(x, s)]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain or point to a resource for the `->` that is not in the type signature? I did not know that the arrows could be used outside of type declarations.

Comment: The `=>` is just the Idris syntax for lambdas: what in Haskell would be `\x -> e` is in Idris written as `\x => e`.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. I was referring to the line `Parser a = String -> List (a, String)`. Is the `->` in this line basically creating type that is a function? And does `->` mean the same thing whether or not it occurs in the type signature or a function definition?

Comment: That one is exactly the same as saying `type Parser a = String -> LIst (a, String)` in Haskell: it doesn't define a new type, it merely introduces a type synonym.

Comment: The tricky part is that `Parser` is a function that takes, as argument, a `Type`, and returns, as a result, another `Type`. It's like a type constructor of kind `* -> *` in Haskell; but in Idris it doesn't need to be defined in any way different than a function that takes, let's, say, an argument of type `Int` and returns a `Bool`.

Answer (score 2):

In defining your datatype Parser, the first line is saying this type takes a type and returns a type, in this case it takes an `a` and returns a `Parser a`.

So, your constructors should return `Parser a`.

Similar to a `List` which takes an `a` and returns a `List a`.

What you are currently returning in your constructors are not of type `Parser` - easily seen as nowhere does the word `Parser` occur on the right hand side.

Beyond that though, I'm not sure how you would best represent this.
However, there are some parser libraries already written in Idris, looking at these might help ? For example, have a look at this list of libraries, parsers are the first ones mentioned :-
[Idris libraries](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Libraries)